# If sum of two vectors is in a subspace then the two vectors are also in the same subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I am self studying studying linear algebra. In solving an exercise I proved the following result which seems to be wrong but I am not able to find mistakes in my proof.

> Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ over $F$. If $a+b=c$ with $a \in V, b \in V, c \in W$, then $a \in W$ and $b \in W$

Notation: I used subscript to differentiate vectors and scalars. $F$ denotes field and $V$ denotes a vector

Proof:

There are $4$ possible choices for the vectors $a,b$.

1) $a\in W, b\in W$

2) $a\in V, b  \in W, c \in W \implies a=c-b \in W $

3) $a\in W, b  \in V, c \in W \implies b=c-a \in W $

4) $a \in V, b\in V, c \in W$,

WLOG suppose that $a \neq 0 , b\neq 0$, (otherwise $a$ and $b$ would be in $W$), then there exists two non zero scalars $a_F,b_F$ in $F$ such that $a_F(1_V)=a$ and $b_F(1_V)=b $.

Now $a_F(1_V)+b_F(1_V)=c$, since $a_F$ is non zero $\exists$ a scalar $a{_F}^{-1}$ such that $a_F(a_F^{-1}) =1_F$, so

$1_V+a_F^{-1}b_F(1_V)=a_F^{-1}c_F(1_V) \implies b \in W \implies a \in W $

Please mention the errors in the proof

Comment: "then there exists two non zero scalars $a_F,b_F$ in $F$ such that $a_F(1_V)=a$ and $b_F(1_V)=b $."  -- What is $1_V$?

Comment: Yes I found the mistake! I assumed it was multiplicative identity which doesn't exist in a vector space

Comment: @5xum So the problem is with the 4th case?

Comment: Well, the mistake is made in the fourth case, yes. But the problem is that youa re trying to prove a statement which is not true.

Comment: Yes It is false, but the problem was that I could not understand what was wrong with the proof

Comment: Then yes, the thing wrong with the "proof" is that $1_V$ doesn't exist in $V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is rather obviously wrong: if $W$ is any subspace of $V$, $c=0$ belongs to $W$ and you can write $a-a=c$ for any $a$. This doesn't imply that $a\in W$.

In the later part of your proof, what do you mean by $1_V$? A vector space doesn't have a multiplicative unit.

Comment: Okay, so my fourth case is wrong where I assumed a multiplicative identity for a vector space?

Comment: Precisely. Basically you're looking at vector spaces which are also fields, that is the dimension is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prove something false, and the claim in your question is false. For example, take

$$\;V=\Bbb R^2_{\Bbb R}\;,\;\;W:=\text{Span}\,\left\{\,\binom11\,\right\}\;,\;\;a=\binom10\,,\,\,b=\binom01$$

You have several mistakes, imo: what does $\;1_v\;$ mean, to begin with?? And your last equation is completely beyond my comprehension, too.

Comment: Sorry I mixed field and vector space axioms